# Would it still be grammatically correct if I omit or add "for" before "number+time(s)"

Tags: prepositions

> 1.I told you three times
>
> 2.I told you **for** three times

Which one is correct or more common? I saw many of them in some random articles, sometimes, it adds "for" before it, but sometimes it is just ommited.

Comment: The first one is correct and is more common. The second one looks outright incorrect to me, but wait for a native speaker's opinion. If you could expand your question with examples of usage 2, that would be nice.

Comment: I might have been prepared to believe the ***for*** version was "dialectal" and/or "uneducated", but checking the whole of Google Books for *for a hundred / thousand / million times* I can't find any examples that aren't either irrelevant collocations or a handful of contexts obviously written by non-native speakers (particularly, scientific writers with *Germanic* names, which may be significant). To me as a native speaker, including ***for*** is *almost* credible, but it just doesn't quite sound right.

Comment: Only 1. is correct. Without additional context/examples, I can't think of a reason you might think to add 'for' here.

Comment: @CopperKettle: It may be that a nns is better equipped to provide the best answer here. I'm not sure there's a "grammatical rule" that really amounts to anything more than *That's just not how we say it* (arguments for *why* we say what we do are probably just "post hoc" justifications). But if someone who speaks a different language knows that *they* have a usage corresponding to ***for*** here, that might be enlightening.

Comment: My wild guess is that the confusion is caused by "for the first/last/Nth time" (e.g. "I've told you for the last time").

Answer (score 1):

In the example sentence only "I told you three times" is correct, but if we changed the wording to "I told you for three minutes," that would be correct, too.

- I did it three times.
- I did it for three hours.

I think the only correct usage of 'for' is when stating a duration (seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc.)

Comment: I told you doesn't really work well with a duration though. I explained it for three hours, maybe.

Comment: **for** is also necessary with ordinal numbers - "for the first/second/.../last time".

Comment: @JavaLatte, the ordinal numbers have nothing to do with "for", because you can't say "for first" or "for second".